# When can we start a question with 什么是……?

Tags: grammar

> The important thing to remember is that word order is the same in Chinese for questions and statements.
> <sub>[Placement of question words](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Placement_of_question_words), Chinese Grammar Wiki</sub>

While the Chinese Grammar Wiki says this, it doesn't give a single example where 什么 is the subject of a question.  It feels like it's ungrammatical a lot of the time:

> **什么是**这？  (What is this?)
> **什么是**我的名字？  (What is your name?)
> **什么是**你最喜欢的颜色？  (What is your favorite color?)
> **什么是**你的水平？  (What is your level?)
> **什么是**一加一？  (What is one plus one?)

But sometimes it seems okay:

> **什么是**美？  (What is beauty?)
> **什么是**百度？  (What is Baidu?)
> **什么是**气候变化？ (What is climate change?)

I'm not precisely sure, but it appears we can ask questions like "什么是[pla pla]？" when "[pla pla]" is some abstract, unfamiliar, or needing-to-be-defined concept.

**Question**: When can we start a question with 什么是……?

Answer (score 2):

> Question: When can we start a question with 什么是……?

1. When asking for a definition

Example:

什么是美？ - you want the answer to tell you the definition of beauty

If the answer is a definition you can use 什么是 to start the question
e.g. 什么是水平 (you want the definition of level)

~

2. When there is a follow-up statement by the asker

Example:

什么是美？ 美就是(insert your opinion on what is beauty)

Following this rule, you can even ask 什么是你的水平？ (What is your level?) as long as you have a follow-up statement

Example:

什么是你的水平？ 垃圾級就是你的水平!